# Get count of several times slots on between given two mysql time slots

Tags: php, mysql

I have several in data and out date mysql "datetime" values. I need to return total count from given time period.

Ex:

```
In time                Out Time
2012-02-02 10:00       2012-02-02 12:00
2012-02-02 09:00       2012-02-02 14:00
2012-02-02 10:00       2012-02-02 11:00
```

I need to get total as ***3*** from **2012-02-02 10:00** to **2012-02-02 11:00**

Comment: A book reference: Richard T. Snodgrass. Developing Time-Oriented Applications in SQL. Morgan-Kaufmann, 1999.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write this query

```
select count(*) from table name where `In time` <= '2012-02-02 10:00' and `Out Time` >= '2012-02-02 11:00'
```

it will give you count 3

Comment: Thank you very much I got it and added for my reservation system

Comment: Finally I Used,

SELECT vvvvv FROM yyyyyyy
WHERE ( start_time >= '2012-10-02 10:00:00' AND start_time < '2012-10-02 13:00:00' )
   OR ( end_time >  '2012-10-02 10:00:00' AND  end_time <= '2012-10-02 13:00:00' )
   OR ( start_time < '2012-10-02 10:00:00' AND end_time > '2012-10-02 13:00:00')
AND booking_type='XXXXX'

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you want the count of items where any portion of the period `In time` to `Out time` falls within, or "overlaps with", your search date period.

First, let's exhaustively examine what an "overlap" in dates means. An overlap is any of the following conditions:

```
                 Start1                     End1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Start2                       End2
 Start2                                                       End2
                             Start2                           End2
```

And is NOT any of the following conditions:

```
                 Start1                     End1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Start2  End2
                                                      Start2  End2
```

If you look carefully, you'll notice `Start2 < End1 AND End2 > Start1` defines this relationship, so this will become your `WHERE` clause.

---

Therefore you should try the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM myTable
WHERE '2012-02-02 10:00:00' <= `Out Time`
AND '2012-02-02 11:00:00' >= `In Time`
```